# gitlab-ci.yml file rule "changes" running even when the file is not changed

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci.yml

I want to run my pipeline only when a selected file (lets call it x.yml) is changed. The problem is that even when x.yml is unchanged, the job is running. When I compare my branch with the master branch, the file shows as not changed. My question is, how does the "changes" keyword really work in gitlab-ci.yml file? Does it compare against an old commit on the same branch or does it compare with the master branch? Also, is there any possible way my files can be changed but not show up in the gitlab compare?

Thanks

Comment: files will be marked changed only when you "commit" your changes. do you commit frequently, or see new commits in your repo history?

Comment: [check this official page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#jobs-or-pipelines-run-unexpectedly-when-using-changes). if yours is not included there, edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: There hasnt been any commit made to that file in 3 weeks. Not sure what you mean by it mine is not included in the official page, edit the question to reflect that?

Comment: check the link above. they say depending on your settings any commit to the repo will trigger this pipeline as if this file is changed. check if you fell into that trap

Comment: an by editing, I meant to write you checked the documentation warnings about this "changes"  pitfall and sure it does not cover your problem or maybe you missed it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The problem is solved. My issue was that the pipeline wasnt getting triggered by the "push" so changes always evaluated to true. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: for future reference, if someone else gets into the same issue, it would be nice to know what you did to solve the problem, so please post your own answer about the solution.